# GAE, How do I run a function of a model at the time the new model instance is created?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How do I perform setup() automatically when a new model instance has been created?

```
class MyModel(bd.Model):  
    setup(self):  
        ...

model = MyModel()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `__init__()` method to do this in addition to its usual work:

```
class MyModel(db.Model): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # run the default code
        self.setup()  # run custom setup code
    def setup(self):
        print 'setup'
```

Comment: @Alden Be careful with this. The constructor is used by both your own code and by the framework when it loads an object from the datastore. Build with that in mind, and don't have expectations as to which arguments will be passed to it (David's example code is good in that respect).